# outlook2010 show all my calender items

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I have many appointments in my calender.

But Outlook 2010 does not shows all the items which are saved.

How can I show all the items which are in my calender in the side bar of Outlook 2010?

Comment: When you "side bar" do you mean the pane on the right when viewing your email that shows upcoming appointments?

Answer (score 0):

Right click in the side bar (To Do bar) and select "Options".  You may not be seeing All Day Events; just check the boxes for Show Appointments and Show All Day Events.

The number of appointments you can see is limited by space.  There is no scrolling past the last date shown.  To maximize the number of appointments shown turn off the date navigator in the To Do Bar Options.

Comment: Thanks but doenst work. My appointments in June are not showed.

Comment: @user1980 - Outlook isn't going to show you every single event in your calendar in a single location. This answer is way to vague...I use Office 2010 every single day and have no idea what the "Outlook Sidebar" is.

Comment: @Ramhound - He means the To Do bar, visible on the right side of the Outlook screen when enabled.  I didn't feel it was necessary to correct him since it was obvious what he meant.

Comment: @DaveBecker - Understandable.  But it wasn't clear to everone.

Answer (score 0):

Go to view > change view > select list :)